# rewrite to another file if .php file not exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following rule to serve the associate .php file

All last directory pathname will go to the associate .php file

```
Ex. /about/ or /about will go /about.php


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`
```

So when I use http://example.com/abc it points to /abc.php, this is working fine. But if /abc.php file does not exist in that directory then I like to forward that to /listing.php file. How can I do that? please help

> Also, I need this to apply to the root directory only. means
> http://example.com/..*here*.. not for any subdirectory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should be tested:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $0\.php !-f //check if (for example) abc.php not exists then
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /listing.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Update: I tested this on my local server, note that: the folder is test you can adjust for your own

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond test\/$0\.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ listening.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: thank for your support, first it was giving me an 500 error then i removed the / and now its giving me same error for both cases weather file exists or not, here the code i was trying
-------------------------------------------------
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $0\.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ listing.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

Comment: I forget to mention the error was listing.php.php not found on this server